# HERE Maps: VIOLATES_OPTIONS error meaning

Tags: android, here-api

I have been getting this error (VIOLATES_OPTIONS) in the field but have not seen it internally. Do you know what causes this error and how it can be avoided? I am using truck routing and typically see it when calculating routes with many stops.

EDIT: Does this mean there is no route that respects the given options? I don't think the vehicle is going anywhere that trucks can't go.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Yes. A route was found but is invalid because it makes use of roads that were disabled by RouteOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the router cannot compute a route that successfully matches the settings supplied by the code to RouteOptions. The router may return a route with error "VIOLATES_OPTIONS", which means there is a route but one or more of the RouteOptions cannot be satisfied.

For example, if you calculate a route with no bridges but the truck has to cross a bridge to the destination.

Or in your case, perhaps there are many stops and there is no way to route a truck successfully under height restrictions.